# What factors influence the "Avoids Enormous Network Payloads" message?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

According to the official documentation, the target is 1600KB: 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/network-payloads

However, even when the payload is larger than the target, it sometimes still shows as a passed audit: 
[payload of 2405KB still passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X81SW.jpg)

What are the other conditions that allow large payloads to pass the audit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lighthouse scores are 0–100 based on some log normal distribution math.

1600KB is not a *passing* score, it is approximately a maximum possible 100 score.

As of right now [the values used for distribution calculation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/c79e3579cbcf214f29680a463be7162e7bdc89fe/lighthouse-core/audits/byte-efficiency/total-byte-weight.js#L48-L51) are 2500KB point of diminishing returns and 4000KB median, which would correspond to scores of about 93 and 50 respectively.

That puts 2405KB result at ~94 score which is sufficient to pass.